# WPF Binding DataTable column to a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, textbox, datatable

I'm getting started with WPF and finding it difficult to get even the most simple binding working.  Here's some givens...

I have an object that queries an existing database and returns a "datatable" object, the data comes back (and for test purposes, only a single row and single column called "MyTextColumn")

The data table is not "Strongly typed" as I've read in other places trying to force the issue of strongly typed objects.  I want to understand the underlying mechanisms from the code-behind perspective, AND not from the XAML perspective.  From reading, apparently you can't bind directly to a data table, but you can to the "DefaultView" of a DataTable object (makes no sense to me since they point to same record (or set of records, with exception of say a filter of some type).

So, in the XAML portion of the window,

```xml
<src:MyWindow blah, blah >
  <Grid Name="grdTesting">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition />
      <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Name="lblMyTextColumn" 
        Content="Just the label" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0 "/>

    <TextBox Name="txtMyTextColumn"
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
        Width="120" />
  </Grid>
</src:MyWindow>
```

So now, I'm in the code-behind, what I've read is you have to have a BindingListCollectionView oView;

```
public partial class MyWindow : Window
{
  BindingListCollectionView oView;
  MyQueryingManager oTestMgr;

  public MyWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    oTestMgr = new MyQueryingManager();
    DataTable oResults = oTestMgr.GetTheData();

    // Data context for the form bound to the Table retrieved
    oView = new BindingListCollectionView( oResults.DefaultView );

    // One place said the Window should get the binding context
    DataContext = oView;

    // another indicated the grid...  Just need to know which I SHOULD be using
    grdTesting.DataContext = oView;


    // Now, for my binding preparation...
    Binding bindMyColumn = new Binding();
    bindMyColumn.Source = oView;
    bindMyColumn.Path = new PropertyPath("MyTextColumn");
    txtMyTextColumn.SetBinding( TextBox.TextProperty, bindMyColumn );
  }
}
```

So...  what am I missing here... Should be simple, nothing complex, I have a data table, with a record, that has a value.  Run the form (no matter binding context to the Window or the Grid), and the record value does not show in the textbox control.  Once I understand the behavior on a single textbox, I can go on with all the other elements (validation, input mask, formatting, etc), but am stuck right at the gate on this one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can bind to a `DataTable` but you can also use the default view (which is a `DataView`) etc.

Usually, you bind a `DataTable` to an `ItemsControl` or a control that derives from it, such as `ListBox`, `DataGrid` etc. Then each container will get a `DataRow` (or `DataRowView`) and the binding will be easy.

Since you are binding it directly to a `TextBox` inside a `Grid` you would have to specify both `Row` and `Column` in the binding. The correct path to bind to the column named "MyTextColumn" in the first row is `Rows[0][MyTextColumn]`

Try this

```
Binding bindMyColumn = new Binding();
bindMyColumn.Source = oResults;
bindMyColumn.Path = new PropertyPath("Rows[0][MyTextColumn]");
txtMyTextColumn.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindMyColumn);
```

A problem if you're binding directly to the `DataTable` is that it doesn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` so the UI won't know that the value has changed if it is changed from some other source. In this case, you can use a `DataView` instead. The binding syntax will be a little different here since you access the `DataRowViews` directly with the index operator.

```
dataView = oResults.DefaultView;
// Now, for my binding preparation...
Binding bindMyColumn = new Binding();
bindMyColumn.Source = dataView;
bindMyColumn.Path = new PropertyPath("[0][MyTextColumn]");
txtMyTextColumn.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, bindMyColumn);
```

Comment: Your solution sounds closest to working, but I'm still getting no output when running the form.  I'm still playing around with options and settings to see what might be the missing part.  Your reference to path as "Rows[0][MyTextColumn]" doesn't appear to work as it needs to reference the DataView which in-turn has DataViewRow object.  So, I'm stepping through in the debugger what I might be missing.

Comment: @DRapp: If you're using a `DataView` as Source, see the last part of my answer. The path should be `"[0][MyTextColumn]"`

Comment: @DRapp: Uploaded a sample application for you to look at and compare to your attempt. It does `DataTable` and `DataView` Bindings: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/DataTableBindings.zip

Answer (score 0):

A Grid is simply a layout panel (think spreadsheet). You have to manually place controls into the cells.

What you are looking for is probably a **DataGrid**, which has the ability to generate columns automatically using reflection (or you can define them yourself). The [WPF Toolkit from Microsoft](http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-datagrid-feature-walkthrough.aspx) has one you can use if you don't want to go with one of the many 3rd party data grid controls.

Comment: I'm familiar with DataGrid binding from C# Winforms, no problem if I wanted columnar output.  However, I want more of a data-entry editing with multiple "groups" of controls.  As if an order entry system you would have a section for customer name/address, other elements for billing, other for comments / notes, like information that would appear in an invoice header.   One entry at a time, never  multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Grid which is a layout control, which means that it has visual elements as children, not items. You should use an ItemsControl like Listbox for example, and bind the ItemsSource property to your collection.

Comment: see comment I put under Philipp Schmid in this question/answer group.